# How to iterate over a vector without moving it

Tags: rust

I have a recursive type which doesn't implement copy

```rs
struct Node {
    board: Board,
    children: Option<Vec<Node>>,
}
```

I have a Vector of these nodes, I want to call a method on each, and then pass them on to another function.

```rs
fn foo() {
    let mut nodes: Vec<Node> = get_nodes();
    for i in 0..nodes.len() {
        nodes[i].grow();
    }
    pick_node(nodes);
}
```

This works, but frustratingly

```rs
fn foo() {
    let nodes: Vec<Node> = get_nodes();
    for mut node in nodes {
        node.grow();
    }
    pick_node(nodes);
}
```

causes an error because "`nodes` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`"

Is there a version of `for _ in _` that just gets me references to each member of the vector in turn, without moving or copying, like I get when I use a range like in the first version? It's an issue that comes up a lot for me, and it's been hard to find an answer for some reason. Like Clippy says, the iterator is probably faster, and clearer, and just seems idiomatic.

Comment: You can take a reference there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the methods you're looking for are [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) and/or [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut). So your code will look like the following:

```rs
for node in nodes.iter_mut() {
    node.grow();
}
```

Alternatively, `&Vec<T>` and `&mut Vec<T>` both have [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) [implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator) which return the iterator provided by `iter` or `iter_mut` respectively. So the following is also equivalent to the above:

```rs
for node in &mut nodes {
    node.grow();
}
```

### Edit

All of the above is correct, just to add a little more clarification:

```rs
for pattern in iterable {
    /* body */
}
```

essentially just desugars to the following:

```rs
let mut iter = IntoIterator::into_iter(iterable);
loop {
    match iter.next() {
        Some(pattern) => { /* body */ },
        None => break,
    }
}
```

[`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) requires an owned `self`, so that's why your vector is moved when it's substituted in the place of `iterable`. Ownership of the vector is transferred to its `into_iter` function. On the other hand, when you put `&vec` or `&mut vec` in the place of `iterable`, it's the references which are copied/moved, leaving the original vector in place.

Comment: I think this is something the docs should do a better of making clear: in a `for` loop, iterating over something by value is preferable to calling `into_iter()` on it, by reference ... `iter()` (when it's defined), and by mutable reference ... `iter_mut()` (when it's defined). You only *need* the  `_iter_()` methods if you want to call additional `Iterator` methods on the result; "plain" iteration is preferable in `for` loops.

Comment: so `iter()` and `iter_mut()` are "plain" ... whereas ...  `into_iter()` is an `_iter_()` method, and better to avoid unless you need it? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: No to clarify what BallpointBen was talking about, if you just need to iterate by reference do `for x in &vec` instead of `for x in vec.iter()`, and similarly use `for x in &mut vec` for mutable references or `for x in vec` for owned values. This syntax is just more ergonomic. You only need the `iter` methods if you want to chain them, for example, `for (index, thing) in vec.iter().enumerate()`.

Comment: While it isn't a hard rule, the preferred style amongst the Rust community is to use `&` and `&mut` over `.iter()` and `.iter_mut()` when possible ([there is even a clippy lint for that!](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#explicit_iter_loop)). Use explicit `iter()` only for iterator transformations (`(&v).into_iter().map()` looks _really_ bad).